# How to specify JS script to be included after ajax call in CListView

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery, yii

After an ajax call I am calling a function

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'viewData'=>array('sent'=>$sent),
            'dataProvider'=>$dp,
            'pager' => array(
                            'prevPageLabel'=>'< Anterior',
                            'nextPageLabel'=>'Siguiente >',
                            'header'=>'Pagina: ',
                            'pageSize'=>5,),
            'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}", //template
            'itemView'=>'_messageView',
            'emptyText'=>'No ha recibido ningun mensaje todavia',
            'enablePagination'=>true,
            'baseScriptUrl'=>'/../../Javascript/messages/messages.js',
            'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:callFunction()',
            'id'=>'listMessages',
        ));
```

The function callFunction() is defined in a separate js file which i include the first time the page loads, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../../Javascript/messages/messages.js"></script>
```

The function gets called the first time i load the page, but after an ajax call it doesnt get called anymore. I suspected it was because it couldn't find the message.js file, so i tried including it again adding this piece of code to the CListView definition:
`'baseScriptUrl'=>'/../../Javascript/messages/messages.js',` but now im getting this error: `jQuery("#listMessages").yiiListView is not a function` ... Any ideas?

**Solution**

```
                    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$ligas,
                    'viewData'=>array('joinedArray'=>$joinedArray),
                    'template'=>"{items}", //template
                    'itemView'=>'_viewLiga',
                    'emptyText'=>'Usted todavia no se ha unido a ninguna liga',
                    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id, data) {myLigasListUpdated();}',
                    'enablePagination'=>false,
                    'id'=>'listViewMyLigas',
                ));
```

The problem was in the signature of the function which had to be called after an ajax update. It had to be like stated in the solution. Thanks @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never a need to reload a script file in order to use functions in it unless you went to a new page or went to a different scope that can't see the functions or unless something destroyed the script tag.  If you're still on the same page and still in an appropriate scope, then the functions are still there.  You should concentrate on why the functions aren't working rather than trying to load a script file a second time.

If you can show us the actual generated javascript that contains the ajax call, we can help you figure out why it doesn't work the second time around.  Much, much better to fix the root cause rather than pursue a hack work-around of reloading.

Comment: You are right. It wasn't a problem of included javascript, the error was in the function's signature. It has to be of the type function(id, data) where 'id' refers to the ID of the list view 'data' the received ajax response data ([says so here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail)). I edited the initial question and included the solution. Thank you!